# getting and passing object to node js render method

Tags: node.js, express

I am playing around with the alpha vantage API and I am having trouble extracting the data in the else statement for viewing on the front end.

Here is my express route:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
var url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=apikey';
request.get({
    url: url,
    json: true,
    headers: { 'User-Agent': 'request' }
}, (err, resp, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
    } else if (resp.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log('Status:', resp.statusCode);
    } else {
        // data is successfully parsed as a JSON object:
        // console.log(data);
    }
})
res.render("index");
```

})

I want to pass the data variable in the else statement to `res.render("index" {//get data into here});`

I have tried assigning the data variable to another variable outside of `request.get({})` but it does not seem to work. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: It's async; you can't render the data before it's available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.get` is an asynchronous function, it means that everything inside the callback function below won't be executed immediately, it will wait until the `request.get` finish calling the endpoint and return the data then callback function will be executed.

```
// the callback function of `request.get`
(err, resp, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error:', err);
        } else if (resp.statusCode !== 200) {
            console.log('Status:', resp.statusCode);
        } else {
            // data is successfully parsed as a JSON object:
            // console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

In terms of execution flow, your `res.render("index");` will be executed first before the callback function of `request.get` (it waits until the endpoint call finished), that's why you couldn't access `data`.

So, in order to `res.render` to access `data`, it should be put inside callback function so

```
(err, resp, data) => {
        // ...other code
        } else {
            res.render('index', { data });
        }
    })
```

good reference to read about asynchronous https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nodejs-eventloop-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You can render it in the else statement.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=apikey';
    request.get({
        url: url,
        json: true,
        headers: { 'User-Agent': 'request' }
    }, (err, resp, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error:', err);
        } else if (resp.statusCode !== 200) {
            console.log('Status:', resp.statusCode);
        } else {
            res.render("index", {data}) // Change to something else
        }
    })

}}
```